# how to update of a form field within a datatable cell

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've got a Datatable set up which contains a form field on each row.

What I want to do is update the value of this field for each row.

I'm iterating over each row of the table with this function:

```
castTable.rows().every(function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ){
                var data = this.data();
                var page_order = data[1];

                console.log("row data:", data[1]);

            });
```

`page_order` then contains the string that represents the field as follows:

```
<input class="form-control page_order" name="page_order[0]" type="text" value="1">
```

I've tried using this to create a jquery object and update the value that way but can't then work out how to place this back in the data object as a string.

What is the correct way to set the value of a form field in the data object within each row?

**Test 1**
This is a method I tried today but doesn't update the field

```
var field = $(data[1]);
field.val(data[0]);
data[1] = field;
```

Comment: Did you check the [API description](https://datatables.net/reference/api/) especially the one for [`.data()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().data()) on how to get and set a value?

Comment: Yes, I've checked the documentation and can update data. In jquery I would update the form field as `$('.page_order').val(7)` for example. So I wanted to do the same to the field that sits in the data object but am unable to do this. Do I simply replace the whole string?

Comment: added an example attempt